# CSS positioning and scrolling

Tags: css, menu, banner

I am trying to get a left menu and a right banner and have them stay fixed in place when the centre panel scrolls text - the banner will have to be on top of the centre panel due to size - the colour scheme is white text on black background except for the menu which is an `<ul>` with its own colour scheme

I am rather new to css so may have already made a prat of myself - I have tried but currently the top right banner does stay fixed when scrolling but the text overlays it and the top left menu shoots off the screen

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a35xe/)

```
<head>
<style>
#container {
    width:90%;
    height 100%;
    background-color:Black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text- align: left;
}
#banner {
    float: right;
    background-color:black;
    width:40%;
    top:1;
    right:1;
    position:fixed
}
#sidebarmenu {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    background-color:Black;
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 20px;
    top:1;
    left:1;
    position:fixed
}
#mainContent {
    background-color: Black;
    color:White;
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
    width: 50%;
    top:220;
    margin: 0 0 0 15%;
}
body {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
.sidebarmenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font: bold 13px Verdana;
    width: 180px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.sidebarmenu ul li a {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #778;
    border-right: 1px solid #778;
}
.sidebarmenu ul li a:link, .sidebarmenu ul li a:visited, .sidebarmenu ul li a:active {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
.sidebarmenu ul li a:visited {
    color: white;
}
.sidebarmenu ul li a:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color:red;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="banner" ><img style="float:right" alt="logo text" src="/banner.png" /></div>
<div id="mainContent" >TEXT</div>
<div class="sidebarmenu">
<ul id="sidebarmenu1">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="1.html">Info</a></li>
<li><a href="11.php">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="2.php">Page 2</a></li>
<li><a href="3.php">Page 3</a></li>
<li><a href="4.php">Page 4</a></li>
<li><a href="5.php">Page 5</a></li>
<li><a href="6.php">Page 6</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

any help /comments / guidance on what I should be learning /looking at is appreciated

Comment: can you post the html as well.

Comment: here is entire page minus the ipsum i was using  - editing original                                              
</body>

Comment: check your post, nothing is showing in respect of html

Comment: took me a while to add all the spaces and was over char limit for comments - hence edited original

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phew! Where to start? lol Your code needed to be fixed pretty much on every line. I have a reworked demo here but basically, you must pay attention to site architecture when you are positioning elements. Organization is everything is front end development.

See [***DEMO***](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjeyn/)

Comment: The main content - can it be lowered ? top:200 seems to do nothing .

Comment: You mean the "TEXT"? Yes, right now I have it at top:-150px; but the position is relative. Every time you position something fixed, you want to position its content relative to the container. So basically the text is  150 px up from the bottom of the parent. The closer to 0px you set the value, the closer you get to the bottom of the container. Makes sense?

Comment: What you have said makes sense but the text ends up at the top of the page and I cant see a - 150 anywhere . had to remove the css for the ul as it broke the positioning but ill redo that soon - http://www.fairfaxs.org.uk/test.html text flows just as i wanted - menu and banner perfect - BUT text is at top of page

Comment: noticed that the text container is on top of the banner -

Comment: so this text is not text for the banner? this is the actual page content?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, once you start using **position: absolute;** or **position: fixed;**, using **float** and **margin** becomes irrelevant.

Also, when using **top: x;**, **left: x;**, **right: x;**, or **bottom: x;** always make sure to add a size unit to your value, i.e. **top:1;** should be **top: 1px;**

If I understood correctly from the css you posted, something that'll get you closer to what you want to achieve is this:

```
html,body{ margin: 0; padding: 0; color: #fff; background: #000; height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
#container { width:100%; height: 100%; text-align: left; overflow: auto; border: 1px red solid;} 
#mainContent { width: 90%; color: #fff; margin: 0 auto; }
#banner { background-color: #000; width:40%; top:1px; right:1px; position:fixed; }
#sidebarmenu { width: 10%; background: #000; padding: 15px 10px 15px 20px;top:1px;left:1px;position:fixed; }
```

Take a look at this **jsfiddle** I made to see what this css does: http://jsfiddle.net/beYuC/

**NOTE:** You might have noticed I made the **html** and **body** have a height of 100%. This is because unless you set a height for the **html** and **body**, any other element on the page you want to make 100% will simply be flattened out.

**NOTE 2:** Be sure to check out this website and its CSS for an example of a well done content container and sidebar menu with 100% height: http://www.jlescure.com/

Comment: you should pick an answer then ;)

Comment: ive currently used your bits BUT i cant get the text to drop down the page top:xxx doesnt seem to work http://www.fairfaxs.org.uk/test.html

Comment: As I mentioned you cannot use only a single number as a value for top, right, bottom or left... if you want your container to go down 200 pixels you need to write top:200px; emphasis on the **px** .